# Livewire Lifecycle Hooks self update to upper

Tags: laravel-livewire

Hi is it possible to make live self update to upper form field payment?
because that works if set another field of form not the same.

```
public function updatingpayment($value)
     {  
        $this->upper($value);
     }


     public function upper($value){
     
        $process = strtoupper($value);
      
        $this->payment=$process;
       
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to reference the field from the lifecycle method, Livewire doesn't know your intention.

```
public function updatedPayment($value)
{
    $this->payment = strtoupper($value);
}
```

Comment: Still doesnt work, its weird, but if i change the field to another, then the values goes to uppercase 
public function updatingpayment($value)
     {  
        $this->tasks = strtoupper($value);
     }

Comment: Notice I used the ‘updated’ lifecycle hook and not ‘updating’.

Comment: I tried , that doesnt work event if i declare another field, here is the code

`
public function updatedPayment($value)
{
    $this->payment = strtoupper($value);
}

     public function upper($value){
     
        $process = strtoupper($value);
      
        $this->payment=$process;
       
     }
`

Comment: You don't need the `upper` function. There is something else going on as in a fresh Laravel install with Livewire that works.